# Как сделать ссылку кнопкой, ведущую на сайт в чат-боте?

Tags: python, telebot

Уважаемые коллеги!
Как сделать ссылку кнопкой, ведущую на сайт?
Вот фрагмент кода:

```py
if (message.text == 'Прорахувати авто?'):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Перейти до сайту')
    markup.add(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Щоб зробити для Вас iндiвiдуальний пiдрахунок вартостi пiд ключ, напишiть будь-ласка яке авто Вас цiкавить. Наприклад:\n - Марка авто, модель та рiк', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
button = InlineKeyboardButton('text', url='link')
keyboard.add(button)
```

---